# Python winreg missing subkey on Win7

Tags: python, windows-7, winreg

I'm wondering why python module winreg doesn't return all the subkeys and values in Win7 host.

If I use native reg cmdline command to query registry I get the following:

```
>reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
    ShowTabletKeyboard      REG_DWORD   0x0
    LastLoggedOnProvider    REG_SZ      {2A1ABE6F-476D-4E5B-FB68-21EF45555CC37}
    LastLoggedOnSAMUser     REG_SZ      DOMAIN\USERNAME
    LastLoggedOnUser    REG_SZ      DOMAIN\USERNAME

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\BootAnimation
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\LogonSoundPlayed
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\SessionData
```

If I use python script to query the same location I only get the following values and subkeys:

> regread.py
>       Values:
>       SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
>        {'ShowTabletKeyboard': 0}

```
Subkeys:
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI
 ['Background', 'BootAnimation']
```

As you can see some items are missing. regread.py seems to work ok when pulling other registry locations and is based on the code posted by Tim Golden here:
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/802172-scanning-through-windows-registry

Does anyone know why winreg wouln't return all the values and subkey from 
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI on Windows 7 host.
I'm local admin on box and even as domain admin it still doesn't work. 
I'm using python 3.3 (32bit) and pywin32-218.

Answer (score 0):

Once I figured out this problem is related to 64/32 bit windows redirection is was pretty easy to get around.

I had to use the following to get registry values from 64 bit hosts.

```
key = winreg.OpenKey(aReg, subkey, 0, (winreg.KEY_WOW64_64KEY + winreg.KEY_READ))
```

(www.stackoverflow.com/ questions/ 8506646/ change-64bit-registry-from-32bit-python)

This site has pretty simple explanation what's happening:

python.6.x6.nabble.com/ Seven-64bits-and-system32-syswow64-paths-td4540789.html

"On a 64-bit system all of the 64-bit commands and DLLs live under \windows\system32 and all of the 32-bit commands and DLLs live under \windows\SysWOW64. 64 bit process gets to see both of those directories as they are but for 32-bit process the operating system rewrites paths and when referring to \windows\system32 OS rewrites that reference to \windows\SysWOW64."